# Comparing C strings with initialized string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

This program is supposed to have an array of 10 string objects that hold people's names and phone numbers. It asks the user to enter a name or partial name to search for in the array, and any entries in the array that match the string entered should be displayed. I'm having problems executing the code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const int size = 50;
    char name[50]; 
    int count;

    char list[] = {"Becky Warren, 555-1223",
                   "Joe Looney, 555-0097",
                   "Geri Palmer, 555-8787",
                   "Lynn Presnell, 555-8878", 
                   "Holly Gaddis, 555-8878", 
                   "Sam Wiggins, 555-0998",
                   "Bob Kain, 555-8712",
                   "Tim Haynes, 555-7676",
                   "Warren Gaddis, 555-9037",
                   "Jean James, 555-4939",
                   "Ron Palmer, 555-2783"};


    cout << "Enter a name or partial name: " << endl;
    cin.getline(name, size);
    cin.ignore();

    for(count = 0; count < 10 ; count++){
        if(strstr(list[count], name)){
            cout << list[count];
        }
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: First, there are eleven entries in your array. Secondly, `strstr` is case sensitive, so "Becky" is not equal to "becky".

Comment: Why are you using C strings in a C++ program ?

Answer (score 1):

First, your data declaration is wrong.  You don't want an array of 
`char`, you want an array of strings, either `std::string` or `char
const*` (the latter only if all of the strings are literals).  Secondly,
you probably don't want the table to be an auto variable; unless you
want to modify it later in the function, and reinitializing it each time
the function is called, you probably want it to be static:

```
static char const* const list[] =
{
    "Becky Warren, 555-1223",
    "Joe Looney, 555-0097",
    "Geri Palmer, 555-8787",
    "Lynn Presnell, 555-8878", 
    "Holly Gaddis, 555-8878", 
    "Sam Wiggins, 555-0998",
    "Bob Kain, 555-8712",
    "Tim Haynes, 555-7676",
    "Warren Gaddis, 555-9037",
    "Jean James, 555-4939",
    "Ron Palmer, 555-2783",
};
```

Otherwise, you want to use `std::vector` and `std::string`, with
something like the above to initialize it:

```
std::vector<std::string> localList( std::begin( list ),
                                    std::end( list ) );
```

(For your example code, this isn't necessary.  You can just use `list`.)

Second, you should use the free function `std::getline`, and read into
an `std::string`, so you don't have to worry about size.  And I don't
think you want the `cin.ignore()`.  This will try to extract (and
ignore) one extra character after the new line, and will probably
require entering an additional new line (since the system won't send any
characters to your program until there is a new line).

And you don't want to use an explicit number of elements to manage
the loop, but rather something derived from the size of the array
itself; iterators would be the most generic:

```
for ( char const* const* iter = std::begin( list );
        iter != std::end( list );
        ++ iter ) {
    if ( std::search( *iter, *iter + strlen( *iter ),
                      name.begin(), name.end() )
            != *iter + strlen( *iter ) ) {
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
}
```

This is, of course, case sensitive; in a real application, you'd
probably write your own matcher (a functional object), which would
implement the exact matching criteria; similarly, you would use
`std::find_if`, something like:

```
Matcher m( name );
char const* const* iter = std::find_if(
                    std::begin( list ), std::end( list ), m );
while ( iter != std::end( list ) ) {
    std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
    iter = std::find_if( iter + 1, std::end( list ), m );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Minor modifications done to suit my compiler, this code works.
  Corrected declaration of 2 dimensional `char list` .
Running here with hardcoded input : http://codepad.org/ZVkbLjHU

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <cstring>
  #include <string>
  using namespace std;

int main(int argc)
{
  const int size = 50;
  char name[50];
  int count;
  char list[][50] = {"Becky Warren, 555-1223",
                 "Joe Looney, 555-0097",
                 "Geri Palmer, 555-8787",
                 "Lynn Presnell, 555-8878",
                 "Holly Gaddis, 555-8878",
                 "Sam Wiggins, 555-0998",
                 "Bob Kain, 555-8712",
                 "Tim Haynes, 555-7676",
                 "Warren Gaddis, 555-9037",
                 "Jean James, 555-4939",
                 "Ron Palmer, 555-2783" };

  cout << "Enter a name or partial name: " << endl;
  cin.getline(name, size);
  cin.ignore();
  for(count = 0; count < 10 ; count++){
    if(strstr(list[count], name)){
      cout << list[count];
    }
  }
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of `int const size = 50;` if you then use `50` everywhere?  And do you really want `list` on the stack, initialized dynamically?  And the `cin.ignore()` doesn't look right either.

Comment: @JamesKanze , you are right. I just posted a quick fix to his code with minimal editing.